# JDialog is Freezing

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

My application freezes and gives me the following error, I will be grateful if you can help me as it is not interpreted and repeated countless times.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)   at
java.awt.SentEvent.dispatch(SentEvent.java:70)  at
java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager$DefaultKeyboardFocusManagerSentEvent.dispatch(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:239)
    at
java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.sendMessage(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:266)
    at
java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:493)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4760)    at
java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)   at
java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)     at
java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)   at
java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)  at
java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)  at
java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)  at
java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)  at
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  at
java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at
java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)   at
java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)  at
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  at
java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)   at
java.awt.SentEvent.dispatch(SentEvent.java:70)  at
java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager$DefaultKeyboardFocusManagerSentEvent.dispatch(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:239)
    at
java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.sendMessage(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:266)
    at
java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:388)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4760)    at
java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)   at
java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)     at
java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)   at
java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)  at
java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)  at
java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)  at
java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)  at
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  at
java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at
java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)   at
java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)  at
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  at
java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)   at
java.awt.SequencedEvent.dispatch(SequencedEvent.java:128)   at
java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)  at
java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)  at
java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)  at
java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)  at
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  at
java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at
java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)   at
java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)  at
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  at
java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)   at
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:190)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:235)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)    at
java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)  at
java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1671)    at
java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1623)  at
java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)    at
java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)    at
com.restaurant.views.login.jButton1ActionPerformed(login.java:523)  at
com.restaurant.views.login.access$000(login.java:34)    at
com.restaurant.views.login$1.actionPerformed(login.java:169)    at
javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at
javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at
javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at
javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at
javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)    at
javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)  at
java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)    at
java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)    at
java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)   at
java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)   at
java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)   at
java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at
java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)    at
java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)     at
java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)   at
java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)  at
java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)  at
java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)  at
java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)  at
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  at
java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at
java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)   at
java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)  at
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  at
java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)   at
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:190)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:235)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)    at
java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)  at
java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1671)    at
java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1623)  at
java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)    at
java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)    at
com.restaurant.views.welcome.login(welcome.java:83)     at
com.restaurant.views.Main.jButton10ActionPerformed(Main.java:1044)  at
com.restaurant.views.Main.access$1000(Main.java:46)     at
com.restaurant.views.Main$11.actionPerformed(Main.java:869)     at
javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at
javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at
javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at
javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at
javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)    at
javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)  at
java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)    at
java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)    at
java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)   at
java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)   at
java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)   at
java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at
java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)    at
java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)     at
java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)   at
java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)  at
java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)  at
java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)  at
java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)  at
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  at
java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at
java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)   at
java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)  at
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  at
java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)   at
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:190)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:235)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)    at
java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)  at
java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1671)    at
java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1623)  at
java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)    at
java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
```

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your code, but based upon the error `java.lang.StackOverflowError at ` I would guess that it is calling itself.

Comment: This is part code                    this.dispose();
                    Main mainForm = new Main(new javax.swing.JDialog(), true);
                    mainForm.setVisible(true);

Comment: Do you have to press the button multiple times to get this error. It seems there's a click on a button that calls `login()` that sets a modal dialog visible. Is it that same dialogue instance, or is it the same event some how repeatedly being despatched.

Comment: thanks for answering,
the main window is frame(Welcome) and open the first jdialog(Login) by a method welcome.login();
the first jdialog(Login)  has a button that closes the current(Login) jdialog and opens the second jdialog(Main):
 this.dispose();
 Main mainForm = new Main(new javax.swing.JDialog(), true);
 mainForm.setVisible(true);
the second jdialog(Main) also has a button to close the current jdialog(Main) and open the first (Login)
this.dispose();
Welcome.login();

Comment: The information you've posted give us no hint, waht's wrong in your code. So if you want to get an answer, please provide your code in form of [mcve] so we can see the cause of your problem and elaborate a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, it was that the first jdialog opened a second jdialog and closed the first by a code that I had added, after doing what I had to do in the second, closed this myself by an event that contained a I guess I had added to open the first one again. After many times I fell into the error of overflow.

I solved it by not closing the first jdialog at the time of opening the second jdialog and then when I did not need the second jdialog, I just closed it, and I had the first one.

Thank you all for your great help.